# When is the localization map injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring and $S\subset R$ is multiplicatively closed subset, i.e. $1\in S$ and if $a,b\in S$ then $ab\in S$.
Consider the natural mapping $\phi:R\to S^{-1}R$ defined by $\phi(r)=\frac{r}{1}$.

If $S$ does not contain zero-divisors then $\phi$ is injective.

I am trying to prove it directly but have some troubles.

**My approach:** Let $r\in \operatorname{Ker} \phi$ then $\phi(r)=\frac{0}{1}$. It means that $\frac{r}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$ then by definition it means that $\exists u\in S$  such that $u(r\cdot 1-0\cdot 1)=0$, i.e. $ur=0$. How to conclude that $r=0$?

If $u\neq 0$ then $ur=0$ leads to $r=0$.

What if $u=0$?

Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: I'm sure that $0$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I thought that the zero-divisor should be always $\neq 0$.

Comment: If $S$ contains $0$, then the localization immediately collapses to the zero ring, because every pair of elements $a/b, c/d$ satisfies $0(ad-bc)=0$.  So... it seems you should be more flexible in the definition and be ready for the alternative use and/or minor slip-ups by an author using this term.

Comment: @rschwieb, I don't understand your answer at all. Could you clarify you comment a bit, please?

Comment: @ZFR Please indicate the unclear part.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a nonzero ring, then $0$ is a zero divisor in $R$, so $0\not\in S$ since by assumption $S$ contains no zero divisors.  So since $u\in S$, we cannot have $u=0$.  (If, as you suggested in a comment, your definition of "zero divisor" does not include $0$ as a zero divisor, then the statement you are trying to prove is not true and you need to modify it to also require $0\not\in S$.)

If $R$ is the zero ring, then the conclusion that $r=0$ is trivial since $0$ is the only element of $R$.

Comment: Isn't  the ideal $I = \sum_{a \in R,\exists b \in S, ab=0} aR$ the kernel of the localization so that $S^{-1}R = (R/I)[(S+I)^{-1}]$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I'm not sure why you're commenting it on this answer...

Comment: because you are the expert on this :)

Comment: @reuns, I am not sure what is meant by $(R/I)[(S + I)^{-1}].$ Could you elaborate?